# Get field of a Matrix in certain locale

Tags: matrix, localization, field

I need to get the content of a field in the Matrix of the English localization in my template. I already have the handle of that field for the current language, but I don't know how to get the English version for that field...

I found this for getting a field of a Matrix:

```
{% set fields = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('news').getEntryTypes()[0].getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
```

But that works of course again only for the field in the current localization... which I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, the final answer:

```
{% set blockHeadingEnglish = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en').first().myMatrix.id(block.id).first().myFiel %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the desired locale by adding `.locale('en')` to your code.

Like so:

```
{% set fields = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('news').getEntryTypes()[0].locale('en').getFieldLayout().getFields() %}
```

Assuming you've got `english` defined as `en`.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Michael, that brings me further.
This already works:

```
{{craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en').first().myMatrix[blockCount].myFieldinsideMatrix }}
```

But I dont know what to fill in for "blockCount". That leads me to a more general question: 
A field inside an entry of a local is always linked to the same field in another local. But the fields inside Matrixes seem not, because I can create completely different blocks for each local.

That meens what I am trying to do is not possible, right?

Comment: What do you need? The same layout of blocks between locales but with translated content? Or a different set of blocks for each locale? In the first case, you have to mark the individual blocks as translatable but not the matrix field (I think), for the second case, you're better off not making the individual ones translatable

Comment: You are right, thats it. Now I am really afraid that all my content (even of the first language) gets lost if I uncheck "translateable" for the matrix...

Comment: Take a backup and see what happens? I honestly have no idea ^^

Comment: ok, this is what I found out: After changing the matrix to not translateable, nothing changes until you edit the content in one of the locals. After doing this, craft copies all the content from that local to all the others. From that point on you can start to translate the fields inside the matrix... this is a relieve :)

Comment: @Jan Just to correct here, Craft doesn't copy "all the content from that locale to all the others" - it only does it for locales where the matrix is empty (which is a relief, otherwise pre-existing translations would be wiped out).